# setting initial state with componentwillreceiveprops?

Tags: reactjs, components, flux

I'm writing an image component and stuck on componentwillreceiveprops.

Here's the gist of the component...

```
class ImageField extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    image: '',
    imagePreviewUrl: '',
  };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
  if (newProps.content === this.props.content) {
    return;
  }

  this.setState({
    image: this.props.content
  }, function() {
    console.log(this.state.image)
  })
}
```

I've got a react form which sends a block of json to the ImageField component that when componentWillReceiveProps fires should set this.state.image to that json block.

However it never sets it and when it hits console.log it returns undefined for this.state.image

Now if I do this.setState twice it writes json to the this.state.image but don't want to do that as it's probably the wrong way of doing it.

Stuck, what's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.setState({ image: newProps.content }, ...})` ? you are setting it with `this.props` which is undefined before it gets set in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: Don't you want this.newProps.content in the setState? newProps will contain the values that are being passed in.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to initialize the state in your constructor as shown below because when the component is created initially, the `componentWillReceiveProps()` is not invoked, rather the constructor will be invoked with the initial props.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    image: props.content,
    imagePreviewUrl: '',
  };
}
```

Next modify `componentWillReceiveProps()` as below so that you invoke `setState()` using the `newProps`.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
  if (newProps.content === this.props.content) {
    return;
  }

  this.setState({
    image: newProps.content
  }, function() {
    console.log(this.state.image)
  })
}
```